# On the fly mp4 processing

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, html5-video, video-processing

Is possible to make such thing? 
I have mp4 files. Client login and start viewing them. I should add client login name and other information to the video output on the fly. It's easy to make offline - process all files by ffmpeg and save new mp4 files. But it doesn't work for me because there're real time information which can't be added offline.
Is it possible to make mp4 processing on the fly?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have already generated MP4 files or you want to generate MP4 files which can have client login and other details?

Comment: I've have already mp4 files. But I need to process them and add client name, logo, time and other info. And it'll be great if I can do it on the fly without delay for processing the whole file.

Comment: Text can be embedded in to the file as a subtitle but to add a logo the whole file needs to be processed. ffmpeg overlay commands can be useful to add logo (i.e. PNG) to the MP4 file.

Comment: and there's no way not to wait until all file is processed? But just to start sending content to client when first frames are ready?

Comment: Fragmented MP4 can be an option if you want to send the file while it is being processed. FFmpeg has that  feature as well. https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#toc-mov_002c-mp4_002c-ismv